# How do I define language-dependent fields in .bib files using biblatex-ms?

Tags: biblatex, translations

I’d like to be able to define field contents in .bib files that will generate language-dependent output in the bibliography.  Something like this:

```
@PhDThesis{Back:DesigningPublicPlay,
  author =   {Back, Jon},
  title =    {Designing Public Play},
  institution = {Uppsala University},
  institution_translation_sv = {Uppsala universitet},
  date =     {2016-02},
  subtitle =  {Playful Engagement, Constructed Activity, and Player Experience},
  isbn =     {978-91-506-2495-3},
  pagetotal = 94}
```

So a document which begins with `\documentclass[swedish]{article}` will get the bibliography entry

Back, Jon. 2016. ”Designing Public Play: Playful Engagement, Constructed Activity, and Player Experience”. Doktorsavhandling, Uppsala universitet, februari.

whereas `\documentclass[british]{article}` will get

Back, Jon. 2016. ‘Designing Public Play: Playful Engagement, Constructed Activity, and Player Experience’. PhD diss., Uppsala University, February.

I know I could use `\DefineBibliographyStrings` to create macros, but I would much prefer to be able to add translations *ad hoc* in the .bib file.

Here is a minimal non-working example input (`games.bib` containing the entry above):

```
\documentclass[swedish]{article}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{biblatex-ms}
\setdefaultlanguage{swedish}
\addbibresource{games.bib}
\begin{document}
\parencite{Back:DesigningPublicPlay}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome. It would be very helpful if you provide a Minimal Working Example with compilable code. Right now, its just guessing. E.g. you give the language option to the `documentclass`. Without knowing the important parts of your praeambel we can only guess which package this option is passed to. An important fact when it comes to language sensitive macros.

Comment: Congratulations on being I think the first person to ask about the `-ms` version - we need some feedback on this.

Comment: Can you have a look at the example file included in this version to see if this helps? https://github.com/plk/biblatex/blob/multiscript/doc/latex/biblatex/examples/98-multiscript.tex

Comment: Well, that’s the one I started from, but clearly did not get it right :-)

Comment: I have mucked about some more, but at the end it seems to me that the given example implies that I have to supply translations for each field separately rather than having a “fallback” to the default field if a translation is missing.  Is this a correct understanding?

Comment: Can you be more specific about what behaviour you expect or want? It's not clear to me what the output should look like.

Comment: As shown in my original comment, in the English version I want the citation to mention “Uppsala University”, whereas in the Swedish version I want ”Uppsala universitet”, therefore my attempt to add the translated field in the bibliography entry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following should do what you want with the currently 4.0 versions of `biblatex` and `biber` from SF (not yet in TL as of 9/9/2023):

```
\begin{filecontents}[force]{\jobname.bib}
  @PhDThesis{Back:DesigningPublicPlay,
  author = {Back, Jon},
  title =    {Designing Public Play},
  institution = {Uppsala University},
  institution_translation_sv-se = {Uppsala universitet},
  date =     {2016-02},
  subtitle =  {Playful Engagement, Constructed Activity, and Player Experience},
  isbn =     {978-91-506-2495-3},
  pagetotal = 94}
\end{filecontents}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[swedish]{babel}
\usepackage{biblatex-ms}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\DeclareMsselect{sv-se}{
  \alternate{translation}{sv-se}
}
\begin{document}
Cite \cite{Back:DesigningPublicPlay}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Note due to the Swedish language setting, the language for all fields without explicit form/lang is "sv-se". So, the selection order for different alternates defined by `DeclareMsselect` is declared for this language.

[image]

Comment: The source above outputs “Uppsala University” regardless of the language setting, at least for me.
I am running LuaHBTeX, Version 1.16.0 (TeX Live 2023) and BibLaTeX has version \def\abx@date{2023/03/08}
\def\abx@version{4.0}

Comment: See modified - the expectation is that all relevant fields would have the different variants and you would select which form to print using a refcontext.

Comment: Right, that’s what I figured was required.  Cumbersome, but there it is.  
While thinking about this I came up with an easier way:  a set of .bib files with `@STRING` definitions for each required language.  I can then write `institution = UU` and if I put `\addbibresource{strings-swedish.bib}` first of bib resources I get `Uppsala universitet` substituted.   I should even be able to cobble up a suitable macro to automatically select the right strings file.

Comment: The ms version is not set in stone, but it's unusual to have just one field with a multiscript alternate.

Comment: Weeeell, my experience when doing bibliographies is that normally people’s names don’t change just because the text is in a different language, nor do the title of the work, name of the journal etc.  But names of universities or government departments look better translated in the relevant language, and of course ”PhD dissertation” etc, but these latter are defined as bibliography strings so they get automatically translated for the language in the bibliography.  (I would like to see strings for “msthesis” and “bsthesis” as well, as I get more of those than MA and BA theses.)

Comment: Actually, the facilities for doing this are in the -ms version already, it has just been so long since I wrote it all, I had forgotten. I need to get a new ms version into DEV and what you want will likely be possible. Will update.

Comment: See updated solution. This need the 4.0 versions of `biblatex` and `biber` from SourceForge until the next TL release of the multiscript version. The `DeclareMsselect` macro is used to declare the fallback list for different alternates.